# Deactivate vs Delete picklist values

Tags: picklist, deactivate

I am quite confused over a question. I know, basic difference between the "Deactivate" and "Delete" i.e. if I deactivate, then I will be able to activate again and my old records also not impacted, whereas in delete, I will not able to retrieve the value again, and existing records will be impacted.

Now, my basic(or childish) question is : Why one would risk of loosing the records value/impacting the existing records. If "De-activating" makes my work, why I would prefer to go for "Delete" option.

In-short, will like to know significance of "Delete"; when and WHY should I use it?

**Update**:What is the limit and impact of keeping values "Deactivated"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may need to eventually delete picklist values because there are [picklist limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=picklist_limitations.htm). Except for some special cases, you can only have 1,000 *total* values split between active and inactive values (500 for multi-select and global picklists). The following table outlines standard picklists with lower limits:

```
Field               Limit
Lead Status         100
Task Status         100
Task Priority       50
Case Status         100
Case Priority       50
Opportunity Stage   100
```

So, if you hit your limit on values, you're forced to delete inactive values before you can add more active values. Certainly, you can avoid deleting values until you're ready, and they never go from inactive to deleted because of age, but they do count against your picklist limits.

Comment: Actually I was not sure about this -> they do count against your picklist limits. And the second guess was about the storage, I thought, it may affect storage as well, not sure though.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, I checked on my production, there are more than 1000 picklist value data. 500 active and 1000 inactive. So this is again troubling me about the limitations.

Comment: @YsrShk Hmm, as far as I can tell that shouldn't be allowed. It's possible the documentation is outdated or incorrect. You might want to submit a case to technical support and ask.

Comment: hmm might be. or it may happen that my client had taken extra by paying extra. bcz i am new to my project, so i don't know past.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox Is there a way to delete the the inactive/active picklist values through metadata deployment via Force.com IDE or workbench?

Comment: @force007 I believe this is something that's being planned but not yet available today. Picklist values not included in a field are simply made inactive, not deleted. If you really want to do a quick clean up, change the field type to text, then back to picklist.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox Is there any possibility to rename/replace existing picklist values which are already used in some records.

Comment: @force007 From the API, you can now change the labels without changing the values, but if you change the values, you'll deactivate the old values (as the above comment). You can fix this later using the Replace feature on the picklist's list of options. I don't know of an API way to do this without touching all of the records.

Comment: @sfdcfox - update on this - We can have more than 1K active values. We need unrestricted picklist values. Steps are -1. Add 1K values then deactive some values lets say x. So after adding x value again, you can Activate existing picklist value again. This will give you more than 1k active values.